# Add Foreign Key to table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to add a foreign key to a table in my sql database in laravel. But after adding I get the following error:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                                   
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `userroles` add constraint userroles_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`user_id`))
```

The table where I am adding this key to is this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('userroles', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
        $table->string('role_id');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

And the table where I am referring to:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->smallInteger('is_responder')->default(0);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The name and the type are the same. What else could it be that I get the error?

**Update**
The field "user_id" in the users table will be a GUID specifically created to each user. This is the field I would like to reference to within other tables. Is this possible? So do I need to make this field a PK then, as far as I understand?

Comment: This usually happens if there is data in the table that don’t have a corresponding record in the other table, i.e. if you had a `user_id` value of `3` in your `userroles` table, but there wasn’t a record with a `user_id` of `3` in your `users` table.

Comment: Actually I just migrated so the tables are all empty yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create foreign key to `id` column of `users` table.

Instead of:

```
$table->string('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
```

Use:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Comment: Am I only allowed to make a reference to the 'id' field? and not to any others?

Comment: You need to reference the primary key of the table you refer to, to identify a row in a unique way

Comment: No, you can actually create foreign key to any unique column, but still you already have integer ``id`` column which is the primary key in ``users`` table it's better to relate to it.

Comment: The user_id field would be a GUID so should be a unique column. How do I make this field primary then to use it as a reference field for a foreign key?